# Save a textfile as current time and date

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

So I am using VB.NET and I got this problem where I wanna save something (this works) but the one thing I can't get to work is that is automatically saves (title) as current time and date (like this as title: 06/04/2015 10h30min25s)
I am using the SaveFileDialog to save my text.

Comment: You do know the slash (`/`) is illegal in filenames, no?  See also [Ask] - this is not a well asked, well posed question

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using the file path as returned by the dialog, you can simply build the path yourself using the current date and time.  For instance:

```
Dim filePath As String = Date.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH\hmm\minss\s")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your slashes to dashes.  You can't have slashes in a file name.